# Unique Login and SQLiteConstraintException

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have the following code for inserting login information into an SQLite database.

```
public boolean addLogin(Login login) {
  SQLiteDatabase Db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
  values.put(TABLE1_COL1, login.getUser_Name());
  values.put(TABLE1_COL2, login.getPassword());
  try {
    Db.insert(TABLE1_NAME, null, values);
  } catch (SQLiteConstraintException ex) {
    System.out.println("here");
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

When I try to test my code with this method executed in my main activity:

```
//Testing Adding Logins
Login login1 = new Login("having1", "fun1");
Login login2 = new Login("having1", "fun1");
db.addLogin(login1);
db.addLogin(login2);
```

I get the error:

```
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting User_Names=having1 Password=fun1
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: Login_Table.User_Names (code 1555)
```

But isn't this what the try and catch statement is supposed to prevent? I also do not see the  `System.out.println("here")` statement. Any insights as to why this is happening much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you should use [insertOrThrow()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertOrThrow(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) method.
`insert()` just returns `-1` if failed.